# auto aim for grappling gun unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'd like to add an assist to my grappling hook cause it's kinda hard to aim it and get it right
i want it to snap to the closest grappable object(like in karlson)
the controller is rigidbody based
grappling hook code:

```
public class GrapplingGun : MonoBehaviour {

private LineRenderer lr;
private Vector3 grapplePoint;
public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
public Transform gunTip, camera, player;
private float maxDistance = 100f;
private SpringJoint joint;

void Awake() {
    lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        StartGrapple();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        StopGrapple();
    }
}

//Called after Update
void LateUpdate() {
    DrawRope();
}

/// <summary>
/// Call whenever we want to start a grapple
/// </summary>
void StartGrapple() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(camera.position, camera.forward, out hit, maxDistance, whatIsGrappleable)) {
        grapplePoint = hit.point;
        joint = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
        joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;

        float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, grapplePoint);

        //The distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point. 
        joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
        joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;

        //Adjust these values to fit your game.
        joint.spring = 4.5f;
        joint.damper = 7f;
        joint.massScale = 4.5f;

        lr.positionCount = 2;
        currentGrapplePosition = gunTip.position;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Call whenever we want to stop a grapple
/// </summary>
void StopGrapple() {
    lr.positionCount = 0;
    Destroy(joint);
}

private Vector3 currentGrapplePosition;

void DrawRope() {
    //If not grappling, don't draw rope
    if (!joint) return;

    currentGrapplePosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentGrapplePosition, grapplePoint, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
    
    lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
    lr.SetPosition(1, currentGrapplePosition);
}

public bool IsGrappling() {
    return joint != null;
}

public Vector3 GetGrapplePoint() {
    return grapplePoint;
}
```

}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis, nulla eget accumsan iaculis, tellus arcu eleifend risus, eu convallis turpis sem vitae augue.

Comment: You have the `hit.point` which is a set of coordinates.  You just need to check all of your grapplable objects and find the one closest to the `hit.point` then change `grapplePoint` to the location of the grapplable object you found.  To do that, you will need to maintain a list of grapplable objects that you can check.  Depending on how many grappleable objects are in your scene, you may need to dynamically filter/update that list so that it only ever has a manageable set of grapplable objects.

Comment: @HumanWrites, won't it aim to the middle of the game object?

Comment: yes, but you could get around that by placing gameobjects at positions where you want the grapple to be able to attach to and find the position of one of those.

Answer (score 0):

How can you make the list, if i may ask?

Sry if i didnt write the right place, its because that i am new to this thing.  =-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).